# Разметка для отображения формул в Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, парсер, visual-studio-2012

Если делать WPF приложение есть ли возможность добавить туда поле которое обладало бы разметкой для нормального отображения формул? Как RichText допустим только не для текста, а для формул. И еще такой вопрос подходит ли WPF архитектура для написания редактора формул? или возможно есть более подходящая для этого среда?

Comment: я занимаюсь WPF. скорее всего есть компоненты, но они платные. А если самому разрабатывать, то лучше начинать не с WPF графики, а со старой GDI (WinForms). там примитивы проще рисуются (это мое мнение).